# Using Delegates and Events with ArrayLists in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, delegates, event-handling

*Caveat*: The example below is a bit contrived, but I am trying to learn about **Delegates** and **Events** in **C#**.

The code below consists of two classes: the *MyClass* class contains an ArrayList as a property, a delegate member, and the Event Handler member. The *MainClass* just has two functions the **main()** one and the function that the delegate invokes called **theHandler**.

My intent is when I .Add to the ArrayList instantiated in the myClass object: *ClassObj* in the do-while loop that the event handler calls theHandler function and writes to the Console what has been added. **However, it doesn't seem to call the Handler function.**

I know that the ArrayList is updating, and when I am using say a (*string*) instead of an ArrayList I am able to get the delegate/event process working.

```
public class myClass{

    public delegate void classEventHandler(ArrayList anArray);
    private ArrayList strArray = new ArrayList();
    public event classEventHandler arrayChanged;

    public ArrayList arrayVal{
        get{
            return strArray;
        }
            set{
            this.strArray.Add(value);
            this.arrayChanged(strArray);
        }
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        myClass ClassObj = new myClass();
        ClassObj.arrayChanged += theHandler;
        string str;

        do{
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            ClassObj.arrayVal.Add(str);
        }while(!str.Equals("exit"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void theHandler(ArrayList newArray){
        foreach(object o in newArray){
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with ArrayLists being used as class properties, but I am not sure.

Comment: How is ArrayList even in your .Net vocabulary anymore?

Comment: Do not use ArrayList.  You should use generic collections like `List<T>`.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Heh, as my vocabulary is now just a few days old, maybe I can get a pass this time. Thanks though, I now know that ArrayLists are superannuated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tne problem is that `ClassObj.arrayVal.Add(str)` does not call the `set` method because it doesn't redefine `arrayVal`, it simply adds another element to the array. You need a method that adds the element to the array and also triggers the event:

```
public class myClass{

    public delegate void classEventHandler(ArrayList anArray);
    private ArrayList strArray = new ArrayList();
    public event classEventHandler arrayChanged;

    public void AddToArray(string value){
            this.strArray.Add(value);
            this.arrayChanged(strArray);
    }
}
```

And then in your loop you call it like this:

```
do{
    str = Console.ReadLine();
    ClassObj.AddToArray(str);
}while(!str.Equals("exit"));
```

You might also want to look into the [ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279274/848330) class. It allows you to set up a handler that is automtically invoked when the list changes

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, ObservableCollections will be my next stop.

Answer (score 0):

Your event will be fired only when you set the property with some new value

```
ClassObj.arrayVal = new ArrayList()
```

Following line will not call `set` - but will call `get` instead.

```
ClassObj.arrayVal.Add(str);
```

Comment: Thank you sir or madam that was exactly the issue. Now that I have learned this, I guess I will never use an ArrayList again, but imagine generics operate similarly in this context?