# How to convert ToList to ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

Good Day Everyone. I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application I just want to ask how am I going to convert this expression from **List** to **ObservableCollection.** Take a look at the 'ToList();' code. I don't know how to change it in order for it to read an observable collection.

```
 CustomerList = _searchedCustomerList.Where(r => r.CUSTOMER_NAME.ToLower().Contains(_keyword.ToLower())).ToList();
```

I'm having problem how to do this because I prefer to use an **ObservableCollection** rather than the List. So I declare the **CustomerList** as ObservableCollection.

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerList;
        }
        set
        {
            _customerList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just do a basic google search and you should get the answer.

Comment: @Rohit Yeah. I just want to have an exact answer that's why I asked it here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

`ObservableCollection <T>` have constructor which takes `IEnumerable <T>`

Example:

`ObservableCollection<Customer> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(myList)`;

Comment: i'm creating a searchbar, so what should be my actual code above be like?

Comment: Initializing an Observable collection kills its purpose. Use `Remove()` and `Add()`

Comment: In your coude can look like

        `CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(
                  _searchedCustomerList.Where(r => r.CUSTOMER_NAME.ToLower().Contains(_keyword.ToLower())).ToList() );`

Comment: For first  time you can create as per @Raskayu, but on subsequent calls intead of calling the constructor use Remove() and Add() methods of Observable collection. Try reading through - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279185/what-is-the-use-of-observablecollection-in-net

Comment: @Rohit Whenever I put your codes, my SearchBar doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the constructor:

```
public ObservableCollection( 
    List<T> list 
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms653202(v=vs.110).aspx

Just create a new ObservableCollection and pass the list as an argument to the constructor.