# windows store dynamic data binding lists and other types

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I hope anyone here can help me with dynamicly binding data. When i add a list item on a button click it does not update in my page, this also goes for adding a value to an int. The int however does change when i type in a textbox... so i don't understand what's going wrong. I also don't know if this is the correct way to go about this.

So for a quick overview of my qeustions:

1. Why does this not work?
2. Is this the correct way to do this?
3. Can someone please show me how to make it work?

the assumed place of error: the NotifyPropertyChanged method in the MainViewModel class.
This is all the code in my project just incase it goes wrong at another place than i thought.

my XAML for the page:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:databinding_unittest0"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModels="using:databinding_unittest0.ViewModels"
x:Class="databinding_unittest0.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Testvar, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Margin="110,10,1023,658"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Testvar}" Height="100" Margin="110,115,1023,553"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Fullname}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Add 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Add1_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Add list item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="609,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="AddListItem_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The c# for the page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

using databinding_unittest0.ViewModels;
using databinding_unittest0.Models;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace databinding_unittest0
{

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainViewModel mvm { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            mvm = new MainViewModel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Add1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mvm.Testvar = mvm.Testvar + 1;
        }

        private void AddListItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mvm.Persons.Add(new Person() { Firstname="Kurt", Lastname="Cobain"});
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

using databinding_unittest0.Models;


namespace databinding_unittest0.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private List<Person> persons;

        public List<Person> Persons
        {
            get { return persons; }
            set
            {
                persons = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
             }
        }

        private int testvar;

        public int Testvar
        {
            get { return testvar; }
            set
            {
                testvar = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
             }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new List<Person>();
            Persons.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "Henk", Lastname = "Jansen" });
        }


        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (propertyName != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The person c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace databinding_unittest0.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Fullname
        {
            get
            {
                return Firstname + " " + Lastname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to Use ObservableCollection<> instead List<>.
Also - Click button event can't be in code-behind of View. Try to bind event. (this is MVVM)

Comment: how would i go about binding that though? also thanks allot

Comment: take a look here :)
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-18-Understanding-MVVM-ObservableCollection-T-and-INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Aaa, you are meaning, how to bind events? Take a look here: https://github.com/gtteamamxx/ZS1Planv2/blob/master/ZS1Planv2/View/TimetablePage.xaml

You have many frameworks to work with MVVM. I used interactivity. (also check viewmodel of this page). ObservableCollection fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Within a view model there are two basic ways to let the binding target (a xaml control) know that something of interest has happened to the binding source (your properties). The first is through the view model's implementation of INotifyProperty changed, which your view model implements correctly by providing a property change notification for the Persons property.

But simply adding a member to the list does not constitute a change to the Persons property itself; that will only happen when you change that property via the property setter, which List.Add does not do.

What is needed is a way for the collection to notify the binding target that something within the collection has changed, and that's done by the collection itself by implementing the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, which List does not do. Fortunately the framework provides ObservableCollection which does implement these interfaces, so simply changing the List to ObservableCollection should do it for you.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279185/what-is-the-use-of-observablecollection-in-net) for a good bunch of answers about ObservableCollectionT>.