# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource binding is not showing data when binding data in XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf

DataGrid is not showing any value when it bind in XAML view code even window data context is defined in XAML all other textbox and combobox data binding on the same view is working fine all of these property are not pasted in following code

**View Code**

```
<Window x:Class="MegaSoft.Views.Windows.SaleInvoiceDetialWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MegaSoft.Views.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="1500" d:DesignWidth="1200"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MegaSoft.UserControls"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MegaSoft.ViewModel"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="Sale Invoice">
      <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel x:Name="_SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
<DataGrid MinHeight="300" MaxHeight="300" MaxWidth="1300" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridCollection,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Name="SaleInvoiceDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" ColumnWidth="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=OneWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="100" Header="Sr. No"  Binding="{Binding Path=SRNo,Mode=OneTime ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" CanUserResize="False"></DataGridTextColumn>


                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

View is bind with view model which contain DataGrid Binding object some and other objects 
**ViewModel**

```
 public class SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
     public ObservableCollection<SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel> DataGridCollection
        {
            get { return _DataGridCollection; }
            set
            {
                _DataGridCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataGridCollection");
            }
        }
 #region PropertyChange
        //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        /// <summary>
        /// Implemantation of Property change interface
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property">Name of property</param>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
// other properties 

}
```

Datagrid show that when i try that

```
_FrmSaleInvoiceDetialWindow.SaleInvoiceDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataGridCollection ;
```

But its not required. it should work as normal binding in Xmal

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridCollection}"
```

**SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel**

```
       public class SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged     {
            GetGeneralData getData = new GetGeneralData();

            public static int CountSRN { get; set; } = 1;

            private int? _SRNO;
            public int? SRNo
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_SRNO.HasValue)
                    {
                        return ++_SRNO;
                    }
                    return _SRNO = CountSRN++;
                }
                set
                {
                    _SRNO = value;
                }
            }


            private int _Id;
            public int Id
            {
                get { return _Id; }
                set
                {
                    _Id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }

            private int? _ItemAccountId;
            public int? ItemAccountId
            {
                get { return _ItemAccountId; }
                set
                {
                    _ItemAccountId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ItemAccountId");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsCatchWeight");
                    OnPropertyChanged("CWSize");
                    OnPropertyChanged("CWQty");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
                }
            }


            private string _ProductName;

            public string ProductName
            {
                get
                {
                    if (ItemAccountId.HasValue)
                        return _ProductName = ItemAccountList.Where(x => x.Id == _ItemAccountId).FirstOrDefault()?.ItemName;
                    return _ProductName;
                }
                set
                {
                    _ProductName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
                }
            }

            private bool? _IsCatchWeight;

            public bool? IsCatchWeight
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_ItemAccountId.HasValue)
                        return _IsCatchWeight = Convert.ToBoolean(_ItemAccountList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ItemAccountId)?.IsCatchWeightItem);
                    return _IsCatchWeight;
                }
                set
                {
                    _IsCatchWeight = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsCatchWeight");
                }
            }



            private double? _CWSize;

            public double? CWSize
            {
                get
                {
                    //if (IsCatchWeight == true)
                    return _CWSize = _ItemAccountList?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ItemAccountId)?.CWSizeOrConversion;
                    //return _CWSize;
                }
                set
                {
                    _CWSize = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CWSize");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private double? _CWQty;

            public double? CWQty
            {
                get
                {
                    if (IsCatchWeight != true)
                        return _CWQty = null;
                    return _CWQty;
                }
                set
                {
                    _CWQty = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CWQty");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private double? _Quantity;

            public double? Quantity
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_IsCatchWeight == true)
                    {
                        if (MaxQuantity.HasValue && _MaxQuantity < (CWQty * CWSize))
                        {
                            CWQty = MaxCWQty;
                        }
                        return _Quantity = CWQty * CWSize;
                    }
                    if(MaxQuantity.HasValue && _Quantity > _MaxQuantity)
                    {
                        _Quantity = _MaxQuantity;
                    }
                    return _Quantity;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Quantity = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaxQuantity");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private string _Unit;

            public string Unit
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_ItemAccountId.HasValue)
                        return _Unit = _ItemAccountList?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ItemAccountId)?.UOM?.Name;
                    return _Unit;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Unit = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
                }
            }

            private float? _UnitPrice;

            public float? UnitPrice
            {
                get { return _UnitPrice; }
                set
                {
                    _UnitPrice = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private float? _Discount;

            public float? Discount
            {
                get { return _Discount; }
                set
                {
                    _Discount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Discount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private int? _DiscountPercent;

            public int? DiscountPercent
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_DiscountPercent == 0)
                        return _DiscountPercent = null;
                    return _DiscountPercent;
                }
                set
                {
                    _DiscountPercent = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DiscountPercent");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }


            private double? _ActualPriceAfterDiscount;

            public double? ActualPriceAfterDiscount
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ActualPriceAfterDiscount = (UnitPrice - (Discount ?? 0.0)) - ((DiscountPercent.HasValue == true) ? ((UnitPrice - (Discount ?? 0.0)) * (DiscountPercent / 100.0)) : 0.0);
                }
                set
                {
                    _ActualPriceAfterDiscount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActualPriceAfterDiscount");
                    //OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }


            private double? _NetAmount;

            public double? NetAmount
            {
                get
                {
                    return _NetAmount = ActualPriceAfterDiscount * _Quantity;
                }
                set
                {
                    _NetAmount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("NetAmount");
                }
            }

            private int? _SiteId;

            public int? SiteId
            {
                get { return _SiteId; }
                set
                {
                    _SiteId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SiteId");
                    OnPropertyChanged("WarehouseList");
                    OnPropertyChanged("WarehouseId");
                }
            }

            private int? _WarehouseId;

            public int? WarehouseId
            {
                get
                {
                    if (!_SiteId.HasValue)
                        return _WarehouseId = null;
                    return _WarehouseId;
                }
                set
                {
                    _WarehouseId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("WarehouseId");
                }
            }

            private double? _MaxQuantity;

            public double? MaxQuantity
            {
                get { return _MaxQuantity; }
                set
                {
                    _MaxQuantity = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaxQuantity");
                }
            }

            private double? _MaxCWQty;

            public double? MaxCWQty
            {
                get { return _MaxCWQty; }
                set
                {
                    _MaxCWQty = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaxCWQty");
                }
            }

            #region DropDownList

_ItemAccountList = new ObservableCollection<ItemAccount>();
            private static ObservableCollection<ItemAccount> _ItemAccountList = GetGeneralData.GetItemAccountListStatic();

            public static ObservableCollection<ItemAccount> ItemAccountList
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_ItemAccountList.Any() == false)
                        return _ItemAccountList = GetGeneralData.GetItemAccountListStatic();
                    return _ItemAccountList;
                }
                set
                {
                    _ItemAccountList = value;
                    //OnPropertyChanged("ItemAccountList");
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<MiscList> _SiteList = new ObservableCollection<MiscList>();

            public ObservableCollection<MiscList> SiteList
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_SiteList.Any() == false)
                        return _SiteList = getData.GetSiteList();
                    return _SiteList;
                }
                set
                {
                    _SiteList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SiteList");
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<MiscList> _WarehouseList;

            public ObservableCollection<MiscList> WarehouseList
            {
                get
                {
                    return _WarehouseList = getData.GetWarehouseList(SiteId);
                }
                set
                {
                    _WarehouseList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("WarehouseList");
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region PropertyChange
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

Comment: i don't see any obvious issues. have you checked if DataGridCollection is filled with data before it gets called first time or that the setter of DataGridCollection is ever used? (use f9 for setting breakpoints)

Comment: i tried that it contain more than 60 items before rendring the view

Comment: can you show the entire viewmodel and also SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel class code? btw. the namings could also be improved and might be part of the issue. Detial should be Detail (a and i switched). WPF often doesn't throw errors in case of typos.

Comment: How are you accessing the SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel instance from code behind? As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` (and all the other Binding properties except Path) on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Comment: SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel added in the question

Comment: actualy SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel  get the instance of view from named as _FrmSaleInvoiceDetialWindow as i mention code in question (_FrmSaleInvoiceDetialWindow.SaleInvoiceDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataGridCollection ;)

Comment: When you debug do you see binding errors in the output window for the XAML binding case?  I normally find the answer to these kinds of issues in those messages.

Comment: Hi Faisal Virk, unfortunately some lines in your code is not syntactically correct thus every reviewer need to go through all of that issues to reproduce the problem on him/her side. For future please provide us with working ready to use code snippets to streamline to process.

Comment: There is only `_SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel` in the view, but apparently nothing like `_FrmSaleInvoiceDetialWindow`. The question still stands, how do you access `_SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel` from code behind to add items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every buddy for contribution. Its works for me by default initialization of the property of Data Grid

```
   private ObservableCollection<SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel> _DataGridCollection = new ObservableCollection<SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel>();

        public ObservableCollection<SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel> DataGridCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _DataGridCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                _DataGridCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataGridCollection");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't see anything in the grid since you have not initialized your collection.
Since you are trying to bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid, you need to feed the data to the collection to actually see any difference.
Then I assume you know, when using ObservableCollection you would be able to quite easily maintain the updates of the collection, more about that is described under this ticket: [What is the use of ObservableCollection in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279185/what-is-the-use-of-observablecollection-in-net)

And back to your issue try the following code:

```
    public SaleInvoiceDetialViewModel()
    {
        DataGridCollection = new ObservableCollection<SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel>
        {
            new SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel(),
            new SaleInvoiceDetialDataGridViewModel()
        };
    }
```

EDIT:
How it looks on my side after the initialization:
[image]