# Any idea why this List setter is not working?

Tags: c#, list, setter

I have a setter for a list which is not firing. Adding a breakpoint doesn't even halt execution, it's like it's just not running the code at all. Any tips or advice on why it's not working?

```
private List<OrderLine> _orderLines = new();

public List<OrderLine> OrderLines
    {
        set
        {
            // Adding a breakpoint here has no effect,
            // and the NotifyPropertyChanged function
            // doesn't get called either
            if (value != this._orderLines)
            {
                this._orderLines = value;
                Recalculate();
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return this._orderLines;
        }
    }

    ...
    
    // I am adding to the order lines like this
    order.OrderLines.Add(line)
```

Comment: `order.OrderLines.Add(line)` calls the getter not the setter.

Comment: Oh really? That seems counter intuitive as I'm not requesting the List, I'm adding to it.

Comment: "That seems counter intuitive as I'm not requesting the List, I'm adding to it." - You are calling an `Add` method on the `List<OrderLine>` instance returned from the `get` property of member `OrderLines`. A property setter is used in assignment of the member (when you use the `=` symbol and the property is on the left of the `=` symbol).

Comment: To call the setter you would need something like `order.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();`

Comment: Right, so I presume you can tell what I'm trying to do (trigger the PropertyChanged event when an item is added to the property). Would you say there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Thate depends: Are you interested in when the collection instance changes (add, remove, etc) or when a new collection is assigned? If you want to know about changes to the existing collection see `ObservableCollection`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4279185/1260204

Comment: Thanks igor, yes I'm interested in triggering a function (Recalculate) and an event when the collection instance changes. I'll take a look into ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter will only be called if you use `order.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>()`
then the setter will be called otherwise you get the Value from it with the getter.